# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^x}{2x-\sin\left( f(2x) \right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, power-series, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

> Let  $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function such that : $f(x)=x-x^3+o(x^3).$
>
> Compute 
>    $$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^x}{2x-\sin\left( f(2x) \right)}$$

My thoughts:

note that :

- $e^{x}=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$
- $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$
- $e^{f(x)}=1+f(x)+\dfrac{f(x)^2}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)^3}{6}+o(f(x)^3)$
- $\sin(f(2x))=f(2x)-\dfrac{f(2x)^3}{6}+o(x^3)$
- $f(x)=x-x^3+o(x^3)$
- $f(2x)=2x-8x^3+o(x^3)$

indeed,
\begin{align}
e^{f(x)}&=1+f(x)+\dfrac{f(x)^2}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)^3}{6}+o(f(x)^3)\\
&=1+\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^2}{2}+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=1+\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^2}{2}+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
\end{align}
or

$\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^2=(x^{2}-2x^{4}+x^{6} )+o(x^3)=x^{2}+o(x^3) $
\begin{align}
\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^3&=(x-x^{3}+o(x^3))(x-x^{3}+o(x^3))^2=(x-x^{3}+o(x^3))(x^{2}+o(x^3))\\
&=x^3+o(x^3) 
\end{align}
we plug those values in $e^{f(x)}$

\begin{align}
e^{f(x)}&=1+\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^2}{2}+\dfrac{\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=1+\left(x-x^3+o(x^3) \right)+\dfrac{ x^{2}+o(x^3)}{2}+\dfrac{x^3+o(x^3)}{6}+o(x^3)\\
e^{f(x)}&=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}-x^3+o(x^3)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
e^{f(x)}-e^{x}&=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}-x^3+o(x^3)-e^{x}\\
&=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}-x^3+o(x^3)-(1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3))\\
&=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{6}-x^3+o(x^3)-1-x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3))\\
e^{f(x)}-e^{x}&=-x^{3}+o(x^3)
\end{align}

> $$\fbox{$e^{f(x)}-e^{x}=-x^{3}+o(x^3)$}$$

\begin{align}
\sin(f(2x))&=\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)-\dfrac{\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
\end{align}
or 
$\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)^3=(8x^{3}\left(1-4x^{2}\right)+o(x^3)=8x^{3}+o(x^3) $

then
\begin{align}
\sin(f(2x))&=\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)-\dfrac{\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)^3}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=\left(2x-8x^3+o(x^3)\right)-\dfrac{8x^{3}+o(x^3)}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=2x-8x^3-\dfrac{8x^{3}}{6}+o(x^3)\\
&=2x-\dfrac{28x^{3}}{3}+o(x^3)\\
\end{align}

> $$\fbox{$2x-\sin(f(2x))=\dfrac{28x^{3}}{3}+o(x^3))$}$$

\begin{align}
\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^x}{2x-\sin\left(f(2x)\right)}&=\dfrac{-x^{3}+o(x^3)}{\dfrac{28x^{3}}{3}+o(x^3)}=-\dfrac{-3}{28}+o(x^3)\\
\end{align}

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^{f(x)}-e^x}{2x-\sin\left( f(2x) \right)}=\dfrac{-3}{28}$$

- Is my proof correct
- Please if you find any mistake try to correct it with details of calculations

Comment: A side comment: There is a tag here called "proof-verification" for every such question. :)

Comment: It isn't *quite* that your quotient is $-3/28+o(x^{3})$, but your conclusion seems correct.

Comment: In the case of [no remainder](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28e^%28x-x^3%29-e^x%29%2F%282x-sin%282x-8x^3%29%29+as+x+to+0) your answer is correct, which is fairly strong evidence in favour.

Comment: i get $\frac{-3}{10}$ which is confirmed by mathematica

Answer (score 1):

We need the following:

As you calculated correctly, the numerator is

$e^{f(x)}-e^x=-x^3+o(x^3)$

but the denumerator is
$$
2x-\sin(2f(x))=2x-\left(2f(x)-\frac{2^3}{3!}f^3(x)+o(f^3(x))\right)=2x-\left(2x-\textbf{2}x^3-\frac{4}{3}x^3+o(x^3)\right)=\frac{10}{3}x^3+o(x^3)
$$

where we used $f^3(x)=x^3+o(x^3)$

Merging both results together yields
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-e^x}{2x-2\sin(f(x))}=\frac{-3}{10}
$$

Comment: it seems that you messed up a two with an $2^3$. i marked in the answer